# Local Notification only appearing in Notification Center when app is open on iPhone

Tags: uilocalnotification, ios5

I'm having a strange issue. My UILocalNotifications are only appearing in the Notification Center when the app is open. If I have the iPhone at the launch screen they don't appear. The icon badge numbers from the notifications do appear though. The exact same code works perfectly on the iPad version of the app. I've verified that the body text is getting set correctly. The app is enabled in Notification Center with all options on as well.

If I have the app open and then tap home to leave the it, the notification disappears from Notification Center as well.

Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

My bad, missed one piece of code when merging from the iPad version.

Jason